# Matrices: Binomial formula and commutative operation

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Reading in lecture notes on the topic of statistical signal processing, I found the following lines of formula that I do not understand:

$$(I)~~Ŷ[k] = \textbf{a}^{H}[k]\textbf X[k]$$ , where $\textbf a$ and $\textbf X$ are vectors of identical length. In the following the dependency upon k is dropped for brevity.

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(II)~~J(a) & = \mathcal E\{|Y - Ŷ|^2\} \\
   & = \mathcal E \{(Y - \textbf a^H \textbf X)(Y^* - \textbf X^H \textbf a) \} \\
& = ~~...
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

$\mathcal E \{\cdot \}$ is the expected value operator which I included for completeness. Just "think it away", I guess it is not necessary for answering the question.

**Question: How did the author derive the second line of (II) from the first line? Is there a binomial formula for matrices? Why is the second Y complex conjugated? Why is the first bracket of the second line of (II) not just repeated a second time after the first? Why are the vectors in the second bracket complex conjugated and transposed?**

*Background: J(a) is a cost function for a minimum mean square error estimator that must be minimized by picking the parameter vector $\textbf a$ of the estimator in a way that J(a) becomes as small as possible. Then the predicted signal Ŷ is as close as close as possible to the actual signal Y by measurement of mean square error.*

Thanks for your support I hope someone is more experienced with this than me.

Answer (score 1):

For real vectors, $x = \pmatrix{x_1 & \ldots x_n}$, compare
$$
\| x\|^2
$$ 
with 
$$
x x^t
$$
and you'll see that they're both $x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$.

For complex vectors, you have to throw in a conjugate on the right-hand term, so that 
$$
\| z \| = z \bar{z}^t = z_1 \bar{z}_1 + \ldots + z_n \bar{z}_n.
$$

That's the first thing you need.

The second is that for matrices, 
$$
(A + B)(C + D) = AC + AD + BC + BD
$$
and in particular
$$
(A + B )(A^t + B^t) = A A^t + A B^t + B A^t + B B^t
$$
In the special case where $A$ and $B$ are both $1 \times n$ vectors, the two middle terms are equal.

That should let you work out what's going on in the derivation above.

I confess, in the stuff you typed, I think that the second $X$ and $a$ should *also* be complex conjugated, but perhaps $a$ is known to be real, and maybe $X^H$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose of $X$ for you.

Comment: Before I work through your answer I want to mention that yes, a is real (since it is a vector of filter coefficients for a FIR filter) and yes X^H denotes the complex conjugate transpose of X (H for Hermitian matrix)

Comment: I think I understood.. The reason, why the Y* is not conjugate transposed is that it is a skalar value und therefore does not need to be transposed, only complex conjugated. The reason why we have to transpose the second bracket is that else the matrix multiplication would be invalid and we have to additionally complex conjugate it because in the complex case we would not get the 2-norm out of the multiplication. Thanks for your help John I really appreciate it.

Comment: OK. Glad it all makes sense to you. This is an amazingly common thing to do in linear algebraic stuff, so it's a trick worth learning.